# How To Make A Child Execute Command Button in C#

Tags: c#

i having a little advance with Command Button

lets say i having a form with

```
label1
label2
label3
```

And one command button of course

before click the command button

```
label1.Visible = true;
label2.Visible = false;
label3.Visible = false;
```

if i click the command button

```
label1.Visible = false;
label2.Visible = true;
label3.Visible = false;
```

and then i click again

```
label1.Visible = false;
label2.Visible = false;
label3.Visible = true;
```

and repeated again, then back to first before i click the command button

i didnt have any reference on this, so i just make a duplicated command button with same position in form, and i use the visible to get the another command button to be clicked

but it looks not cool,

is there any way better than i make?

Comment: didn't got exact scenario.

Comment: so when i click first time, its executed the first code i make, second time, its executed the second code i make, 
third time, its executed the third code i make, 
and fourth time, its returning before i click.
does my explanation are too hard too explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make one button, and count the number of clicks the user has done, depending on the mod operation you can invoke any of the three method you provide, something like this:

```
   int count = 1; //count clicks    
   private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if(count%2 == 0)
           {
              label1.Visible = false;
              label2.Visible = true;
              label3.Visible = false;
           }
           else if(count%3 == 0){
              label1.Visible = false;
              label2.Visible = false;
              label3.Visible = true;
           }
           else{
             label1.Visible = true;
             label2.Visible = false;
             label3.Visible = false;
           }
        count++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this will allow you to only have one command button.

```
public int visibleLabel = 1;

private void commandButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.visibleLabel += 1;
  if (this.visibleLabel == 4) this.visibleLabel = 1

  label1.visble = false;
  label2.visble = false;
  label3.visble = false;

  switch (this.visibleLabel)
  {
    case 1:
      label1.visble = true;
    break;
    case 2:
        label2.visble = true;
    break;
    case 3:
        label3.visble = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you might want to consider having a single label and changing the text (assuming they are in the same locations as well)

Comment: so the click button will adding a new value to the variable then

Comment: Yes, and also test the state of the variable to determine which label to show.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use a flag to track the current status of the command button? If I understand your question right you want a single command button that sets label2 to visible at first click and label3 visible at second click and label1 visible on third click. Do something like this in the command button click handler:

```
switch (status)
        {
            case 0:
                {
                    label1.Visible = false;
                    label2.Visible = true;
                    label3.Visible = false;
                    status = 1;
                    break;
                }
            case 1:
                {
                    label1.Visible = false;
                    label2.Visible = false;
                    label3.Visible = true;
                    status = 2;
                    break;
                }
            case 2:
                {
                    label1.Visible = true;
                    label2.Visible = false;
                    label3.Visible = false;
                    status = 0;
                    break;
                }
        }
```

Some of the code is redundant, and of course you should have a integer variable called status somewhere in your class. Anyway, this should be fairly understandable and I hope it helps.

Comment: lols and the variable will come back to the first time.
first the status must be 0 then to come to the case 0