# How To Make A Child Execute Command Button with Looping

Tags: c#, loops, switch-statement

Okay, so this is an advanced method from my yesterday question

```
switch (status)
    {
        case 0:
            {
                label1.Visible = false;
                label2.Visible = true;
                label3.Visible = false;
                status = 1;
                break;
            }
        case 1:
            {
                label1.Visible = false;
                label2.Visible = false;
                label3.Visible = true;
                status = 2;
                break;
            }
        case 2:
            {
                label1.Visible = true;
                label2.Visible = false;
                label3.Visible = false;
                status = 0;
                break;
            }
    }
```

i using this switch flag in my command button and succes a lot
but i figure out something cool with this, so i thinking a big advanced this and possible that is like this

```
while (true)
{
    switch (status)
    {
        case 0:
            {
                label1.Visible = false;
                label2.Visible = true;
                label3.Visible = false;
                status = 1;
                break;
            }
        case 1:
            {
                label1.Visible = false;
                label2.Visible = false;
                label3.Visible = true;
                status = 2;
                break;
            }
        case 2:
            {
                label1.Visible = true;
                label2.Visible = false;
                label3.Visible = false;
                status = 0;
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

so i just using a single command button then all of the case in switch began repeated and repeated over.
But this logic is total failure, nothing comes to my idea when i executing the program.
I already done this with incremented loop and failure too,
is there any possibility with while loop on this case?

Comment: What in the world are you trying to do?

Comment: @nphx i wanna making a repeated switch program

Comment: Did you intend for those `break` statements to jump out of the loop?

Comment: @nphx hm, i didnt get what your mean, my idea is just to looping the switch statement so i didnt have to even click the command button to repeated it more and more

Comment: That's exactly what you have done. What is the point of that?

Comment: what is your problem, i dont get it.. 'How To Make A Child Execute Command Button in C# with Looping'? what is 'child' and where is 'Command Button'?

Comment: @nphx my while(true) is total failure yet i wanna looping the switch statement and my idea was failure

Comment: @har07 see my yesterday question then
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20161768/how-to-make-a-child-execute-command-button-in-c-sharp
and this is the advanced method from my idea

Comment: how is the failure? is the program not responding? or all labels stay there like before you clicked the button?

Comment: @har07 yes the program isnt responding

Comment: so thats because you do a never ending operation (the while(true) loop) in UI thread. That operation blocking your UI work.

Comment: If you move this to a different thread, the labels will cycle in visibility. Is it what you're trying to do?

Comment: @har07 so u saying, its impossible doing a never ending loop in GUI application ? Okay if u say so, but im using incremented loop is failure too. (i dont know, if the program read looping so fast or not, but i didnt even see switching after command button click)

Comment: @nphx nah you get what i mean, cool :D

Answer (score 0):

After clicking button1, this piece of code will show and hide labels indefinitely. See if it is what you wanted.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;

    var t = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Switcher);
    t.Start();
}

private void Switcher()
{
    int status = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        switch (status)
        {
        case 0:
            label1.Visible = false;
            label2.Visible = true;
            label3.Visible = false;
            status = 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            label1.Visible = false;
            label2.Visible = false;
            label3.Visible = true;
            status = 2;
            break;
        case 2:
            label1.Visible = true;
            label2.Visible = false;
            label3.Visible = false;
            status = 0;
            break;
        }

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
    }
}
```

Comment: var t = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Switcher);
its not a valid object sir,
but System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200); is available

Comment: @Geofff Are you using an older version of .NET than 4.0?

Comment: true, im using .NET 2.0
so this is only available in .NET 4.0 then

Comment: @Geofff You can use `var t = new System.Threading.Thread(Switcher);` instead.

Comment: "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Form1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."
by the way what is the intent of code u making ? i wonder ...

Comment: It works for me on .NET 4.0. The solution for your problem is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c).

Comment: but it doesnt work on .NET 4.0 sample i make,
lemme read the link you give to me for a while

Comment: @Geofff If I start the application without debugging, it works fine. With debugging I get the same error.

Comment: lols,
are u have another idea?
to be honest i didnt know anything about threading nor multithreading stuff